# Make object equal to another, internally

Tags: c#, reflection, copy, deep-copy

Given an object `A`, of type `MyObj`, and an object `B` also of the same type, what is the best way to define a method in `MyObj` which would take a `MyObj` argument and set the current object equal to that one.

Example:

```
class MyObj 
{ 
    /*lots of fields*/
    public void SetEqual(MyObj other)
    {
        /* What should go here, so that when the method ends, this is equal to other in every field OR they are ReferenceEqual */
    }
}
```

Currently the only way I can think of is reflection or manually setting each value equal (not refactor friendly) - there's no way to make the current object an alias to another one (similar to `ref` keyword), for obvious reasons, to gain reference equality, so value equality is the only way - Is there a more efficient and pragmatic way to do this (reflection is slow; manual is clunky), or not?

Comment: What do you mean by this is immutable. If true, then a mutating method like SetEqual is not going to be available.

Comment: You can't change the value of `this` internally

Comment: Under the covers, this is a pointer to the bit of memory containing the current object instance. Even if you could mutate it, nothing outside the specific instance can see your pointer. If they reference a property on your object, it would be your object, not other, that is being considered. What do you mean when you call your objects equal? By default, two objects are only equal if they point to the exact same thing.

Comment: @AdamG I've edited my post to hopefully make my statement clearer. Simply, there is no way to gain reference equality, as it wouldn't make sense, so what's the best way to get value equality?

Comment: You need to specify what it means for them to have value equality in your context. Do you mean that some/all public properties/fields are equal? What about reference properties? Do they need to point to the same object instance or do those referenced objects only need to be considered equal by context specific comparisons? If both instances have null fora given property, in your context does that make them equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 4 methods come to mind.
(11/13/2018) Edited: Added Method 4

**Method 1**:

Code to manually retrieve each individual property from other, and store it into the current instance of the object.

*Upsides:*

- (relatively) Fast
- Explicit control over which properties are pulled over (in case you
  want to exclude some properties)
- Explicit control on deepness versus shallowness of each property

*Downsides:*

- Maintenance
- Easy to miss when a future developer (maybe you, maybe not) adds a new field/property to the class

It could look something like this:

```
class MyObj 
{ 
    public void SetEquals(MyObj other)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return; // We are equal by reference, so do nothing.
        if (other == null) return; // Throw ArgumentException? Up to you.
        this.Property1 = other.Property1;
        this.Property2 = other.Property2;
        this.Property3 = other.Property3;
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Method 2**:

Write a custom reflection-helper class. I'd probably make it static, with a few public static methods, and internally store reflected types and requisite data in a dictionary or something keyed by Type, and containing the reflected info, so you avoid repeating reflection on the same type each invocation. It'll still be more expensive computationally the first time you use it for any given type, but afterwards, it'll be faster, so long as you used some sort of cache. Additionally, you can look into creating a custom attribute to indicate to your reflection helper-class for OverrrideObjectByValue to ignore specific properties/fields.

*Upsides*:

- Almost no maintenance
- Can be written with attributes that you decorate properties/fields
  with to guide the reflector on how to work

*Downsides*:

- Slow (at least for initial reflection, but if you cache it'll be
  faster)
- Complex to write, if you have little to no experience with Reflection
- Writing it to support deep versus shallow copy of nested types within nested types could become an inherently recursive problem, with complex attribute-systems to support granular control of deep vs. shallow cases

You could do it something like this...

```
using System.Reflection;
public static class OverrideObjectValues
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Tuple<PropertyInfo[], FieldInfo[]>> cachedLookup = new Dictionary<Type, Tuple<PropertyInfo[], FieldInfo[]>>

    // Copies fields and properties from the right object into the left object.
    // Could be extended to support attribute-level customization
    // guiding this reflector on properties/fields to ignore,
    // And whether to perform a deep or shallow copy of reference types
    // for instance properties of types left and right.
    public static void OverrideValues(object left, object right)
    {
        // They are equal by reference, we're done.
        // This also handles the case that both left and right are null.
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, right)) return;

        // One or the other is null; we can't do this.
        // Alternatively, throw an ArgumentException here?
        if (left == null || right == null) return;

        // The types mismatch; we can't do this.
        // Alternatively, throw an ArgumentException here?
        // Note: We could modify this to support the case where
        // Left or Right inherits from the other, but that becomes
        // more complex, and is beyond the scope of what
        // you're asking for.
        if (left.GetType() != right.GetType()) return;

        Type leftType = left.GetType();

        if (!cachedLookup.ContainsKey(leftType))
        {
            // Add type to cache
            cachedLookup.Add(leftType, new Tuple<PropertyInfo[], FieldInfo[]>(leftType.GetProperties(), leftType.GetFields()));
        }

        // Iterate around each property, and copy-by-value from right into left.
        // Do the same for each field, for the type we cached in the dictionary.
        // You can add support to exclude properties/fields which are decorated
        // with custom attributes. If you do support guiding by custom attributes,
        // I'd exclude these types in the lookup/cache step in the dictionary before this point.
        // You could even add support to differentiate between structs and classes,
        // and do deep / shallow copies accordingly...
    }
}
```

**Method 3**:

When you want to override instance `A` of `MyObject` with values for instance `B` of `MyObject`, you could just use the assignment-operator to literally make them equal by reference. Be warned: Doing this means they are the same instance, which means making changes to `A` are reflected in `B`, since `A` and `B` are the same object in memory.

*Upsides*:

- Fastest
- Easiest to understand in the future (assuming you know how reference types function)
- Maintenance

*Downsides*:

- Not a deep copy

It'd be as simple as:

```
// Populate list of objects.
List<MyObj> objects = GetObjectsSomehow(); 

// Copy by reference object at index 4 over object at index 5.
objects[5] = objects[4];
```

As you well know, this example for Method 3 is *not* a deep copy / overwrite of the original data, but instead is making the two (in this case I'm storing them in a list) the same - by reference. This is especially useful if the object is immutable, since this doesn't, you know, violate the entire principal of immutability...

**Method 4**:

(Added this method after a comment)
This method is really just syntactic sugar, and really would be best just left as an assignment-operator, but if you really want a method for some reason, you *could* do this...

*Upsides*:

- Sounds like it may be what you're looking for?
- Same thing (Basically) as just using Method 3, setting equal by reference, using the assignment operator...

*Downsides*:

- Hacky and unnecessary approach when a simple `a = b`; would suffice...

Some arbitrary custom type with only fundamental datatypes:

```
public class CustomType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

And then you could have some static class with extension methods...

```
public static class CopyUtilities
{
    public static void MakeReferenceEqual<T>(this T left, ref T right) where T : class
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, right)) return; // we're reference-equal, so be done.
        right = left;
    }
}
```

Which you could then use like this:

```
CustomType a = new CustomType();
a.ID = 42;
a.Name = "Myself";

CustomType b = null;
a.MakeReferenceEqual(ref b);

// a.ID == b.ID
// a.Name == b.Name
// a == b, by reference.
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I considered the last one, but as this method is internal to the class, and this is immutable (for obvious reasons) I can't change the reference. Thank you for the reflection/cache idea though!

Comment: Well, if your MyObj object is immutable, you really *shouldn't* use the reflection/cache approach to modify the objects, nor should you even support Method 1... If an object is immutable, you should not - by definition - be allowed to make changes, as that can ruin hashed types (Dictionary, HashSet, etc...). I would recommend you review your understanding of an immutable object... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Comment: No, the `this` keyword is immutable, I'm badly wording it. Because the method is part of `MyObj`, inside the method you can't change the reference of it

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely. You'd have to use Method 3, the assignment-operator *outside* of the class, as demonstrated in my example. It's sort of the equivalent to replacing invocations to MyObj.SetEqual() to instead be just "a = b;"-style statements, in the driving code referencing instances of MyObj.

Also, note: I added Method 4, which is syntactic sugar with an extension method to allow an instance of any object make a value which is reference equal to themselves. I should probably modify it to restrict to non-structs, but I forgot to do that initially.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what *reference equals* really means.

Two variables are said to be reference equal when they both reference the *same* object(*). Two objects are not reference equal because thats nonsensical; if they are two distinct objects then they can never be reference equal by definition.

Now, what your method `SetEqual` can do is make two distinct objects equal when equality has value semantics. What equality value semantics looks like for your particular types only you can know.

(*)Note that according to that definition, a value type can never reference equal anything because value type variables don't store a reference.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!, However, I do understand ref/value equality - I may have badly worded my question. I meant, make the 2 objects value equal [possible], or, hypothetically, make them reference equal (different variable name, same bound reference - an alias, like the `ref` keyword, however, there seems to be no way to achieve this